# How does the cross-entropy error function work in an ordinary back-propagation algorithm?

Tags: neural-network, backpropagation

I'm working on a feed-forward backpropagation network in C++ but cannot seem to make it work properly. The network I'm basing mine on is using the cross-entropy error function. However, I'm not very familiar with it and even though I'm trying to look it up I'm still not sure. Sometimes it seems easy, sometimes difficult. The network will solve a multinomial classification problem and as far as I understand, the cross-entropy error function is suitable for these cases.
Someone that knows how it works?

Comment: I'm not intimately familiar with neural nets, but even so, your question sounds quite vague.  What exactly is it you're having trouble with?  If you can narrow down the issues a bit, you're more likely to get a useful answer.

Comment: Well, basically I just don't know how the algorithm is supossed to look like. Or, to try to narrow it down, how is the error gradient calculated and how is the error backpropagated using the cross-entropy error function? The network uses the sigmoid activation function.

Answer (score 4):

Ah yes, good 'ole backpropagation. The joy of it is that it doesn't really matter (implementation wise) what error function you use, so long as it differentiable. Once you know how to calculate the cross entropy for each output unit (see the [wiki article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-entropy)), you simply take the partial derivative of that function to find the weights for the hidden layer, and once again for the input layer.

However, if your question isn't about implementation, but rather about training difficulties, then you have your work cut out for you. Different error functions are good at different things (best to just reason it out based on the error function's definition) and this problem is compounded by other parameters like learning rates.

Hope that helps, let me know if you need any other info; your question was a lil vague...